# get data from combination of dictionary and array from plist in swift 2.2

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift2

I hava a plist file which configuration is like this.

Its root is a `dictionary` which has 3 item, item1,item2,item3

Item 3 itself is an `array`.

When i get the values of the root_dict, then the item3 returns the value as `array`.

Item3 has an item (item4) which is a `dictionary`. Item 4 has an item(item5)

i want to get the value of item5

```
root_dict 
    item1 --- string
    item2 --- dict
    item3 --- array
        |
        ------ item 4 ---- dic
                 |
                 -------------item5----array
```

i am using the below code:

```
    var myDict: NSDictionary?


    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("info", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) //mydict has 3 item
    }

    var dicData = myDict!["item3"] as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

    for (key, value) in dicData{

        print(key)
    }
```

its not working.

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to convert Array to Dictionary that is not possible please change you code like this `var dicData = myDict!["item3"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]`

Comment: if i use ur code, it gives Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x7fff764d25c8) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fff764d2aa0).

Comment: Looks like your plist root object it is an Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally got the answer.But i want to clear the concept first.

```
1. first, root returns a dict key.One of the dict key is array.
2. so, first from dict, i have to get that array.
3. Again, array contains an dict item. so i have to convert the array to dict.
```

i use a function, where i pass the key as my required. i can use this function 2 or 3 times or as my wish based on key.

```
//get the plist and get the root dict
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("test", ofType: "plist") 
    {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    }
```

than use the below function in loop 2 or 3 or 4 or more based on dict key.

```
var array:NSArray? //declare array

func convertArrayToDictFromPlist(keyName:String) {

   var dictArray = [NSDictionary]()

    for (key, value) in myDict!{

        //print(key)
        if(key.isEqual(keyName)){

            array = myDict![keyName] as! NSArray//convert dict key to array

            for i in 0..<array!.count{

                myDict = array![i] as! NSDictionary // if that array contains a dict item, convert and append that dict
                dictArray.append(myDict!)
            }

            print(key)
            break

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am totally agree with @Nirav Do as follow might be work for you.

```
    var myDict: NSDictionary?


        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("fetchData", ofType: "plist") {
            myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) //mydict has 3 item
        }

        var dicData = myDict!["item3"] as! NSArray
        print(dicData.valueForKey("item5"))
```

Your console output should be
(
        (
         //Here is your data
    )
)

Comment: actually it returns the full item 4, but i want only the value of item 5. If item4 has many other item.

Comment: item3 returns array where the item 4 is a dict item. How i can get the item4 dict value from returned array?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("info", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) //mydict has 3 item
}
let dicData = myDict!["item3"] as! [[String : AnyObject]] // If this not work try this below statment

//let dicData = myDict!["item3"] as! NSArray

//Now get your dictionary object from array like this

let dic = dicData.firstObject as! [String : AnyObject]
let item5Array = dic["item5"] as! NSArray
print(item5Array) // item5Array is array that you want.
```